# Prorating/refunding the cost of a previous stripe plan when creating a new plan and subscribing user to it

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

I basically want to know whether Stripe is automaticall refunding customers a prorated amount.

My process for updating a customer to a new plan:

1. Delete the old plan.
2. Create the new plan.
3. Create the new subscription.
4. Update user to new subscription.

Answer (score 1):

If you [create a new subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) then [cancel the old one](https://stripe.com/docs/api#cancel_subscription), the customer will be billed for the new subscription but will not gain any credit or refund for the unused time on the old subscription.

If you [update the existing subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription) to switch from the old plan to the new one, then by default Stripe will compute the proration (you can disable this by setting `prorate` to `false` in the subscription update request).

If the proration ends in favor of the customer, they will be granted credit in the form of a negative [account balance](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object-account_balance). Customers' account balances are applied to future invoices before trying to actually charge the customer. Stripe will not partially or totally refund any past charges.

You can read more about subscription updates and proration in [this paragraph](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/guide#upgrading-or-downgrading-plans) of the [subscription integration guide](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/guide).